# if as a ternary operator python

Tags: python, if-statement, ternary-operator

I'm trying to take this function (which runs):

```
def shift_on_character(string, char):
    final = list(string)
    a = [i for index, i in enumerate(string) if i.lower() == char.lower()]
    for i in range(0,len(string)):
        if string[i] != a[0]:
            final.append(string[i])
            final.pop(0)
        else: break
    print(final)
shift_on_character("zipfian", "f")
```

And simplify it as much as possible. Specifically, I'm trying to use a ternary operator on the if statement to shorten that section to one line of code.
I want to write:

```
def shift_on_character(string, char):
    final = list(string)
    a = [i for index, i in enumerate(string) if i.lower() == char.lower()]
    for i in range(0,len(string)):
        final.append(string[i]) & final.pop(0) if string[i] != a[0] else break
   print(final)
shift_on_character("zipfian", "f")
```

But I keep getting some random syntax error when simplifying the if statement. If I make a simpler action for the "true" condition case or if I take the else off then I still get an error which implies that python is having trouble with the "if" condition.

What's happening and how can I fix it?

Thanks!

Comment: You cannot use `break` with the ternary operator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use `break` with the ternary operator. If I understand your function (which rotates around the first instance of char it finds), then why not implement simply as:

```
def shift_on_character(string, char):
    try:
        pos = string.index(char)
        return string[pos:] + string[:pos]
    except IndexError:
        # what do you want to do if char is not in string??
        return string
```

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

It would be simpler (and quite a bit faster) to use Python's built-in functions:

```
def shift_on_character(string, char):
    try:
        index = string.lower().index(char.lower())
        string = string[index:] + string[:index]
    except ValueError:
        pass
    return list(string)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is using `break` as a part of the ternary `if`. If you really want to use a ternary if, you can do it like this:

```
def shift_on_character(string, char):
    final = list(string)
    a = [i for index, i in enumerate(string) if i.lower() == char.lower()]
    for i in range(0,len(string)):
        if string[i] == a[0]: break
        final.append(string[i]) or final.pop(0) if string[i] != a[0] else False
    print(final)
shift_on_character("zipfian", "f")
```

This works because you aren't really using the result of the expression and are just relying on it's side effects. In general this really isn't a good practice and I would just keep the original expression you had before.

Comment: this solution gives a type error (TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'NoneType' and 'str')

Comment: Yeah, I realized I had left the `&` in there, and changed it to an `or`, which works with None types. Still, @donkopotamus's solution is much better.